# T-SQL join table to itself and display value from one row for all values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I do apologize if this has been asked before. I have been looking for this answer for days and apparently cannot find the right combination of search terms.

I basically have a table where multiple records are related by one column. Looks basically like this.

```
ColA | ColB | ColC
1    |   A  |   B
1    |   C  |   D
1    |   E  |   D
```

So Column A will have the same value relating the records. I need to select the value of Column B   based on its value in Column C. Make sense? Basically for this set of data, I need the bottom two rows of data except the first row's value from ColB.  Looks like this.

```
ColA  |  ColB  |  ColC
 1    |   A    |   D
 1    |   A    |   D
```

Here is my select statement I have started returning too many records.

```
SELECT 
    ColA, ColB, ColC, 
FROM 
    TABLE as T1 
INNER JOIN
    TABLE as T2 on T2.ColA = T1.ColA
```

Comment: It is unclear to me how B and C would be related, or why "for this set of data" that is the result you need.  The query you are using doesn't do anything to relate them either, just a cross-join between all the rows with a common value in ColA.  A lot of missing information here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are trying to achieve. Try the script below.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      ColA INT
    , ColB CHAR(1)
    , ColC CHAR(1)
    );
INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( ColA, ColB, ColC )
VALUES  ( 1  -- ColA - int
          , 'A'  -- ColB - char(1)
          , 'B'  -- ColC - char(1)
          ),
        ( 1  -- ColA - int
          , 'C'  -- ColB - char(1)
          , 'D'  -- ColC - char(1)
          ),
        ( 1  -- ColA - int
          , 'E'  -- ColB - char(1)
          , 'D'  -- ColC - char(1)
          );

DECLARE @ColCValue CHAR(1)= 'D';

SELECT  Tbl1.*
FROM    #temp AS Tbl1
        INNER JOIN #temp AS Tbl2
        ON Tbl2.ColA = Tbl1.ColA
WHERE   Tbl1.ColC = @ColCValue
GROUP BY Tbl1.ColC
      , Tbl1.ColA
      , Tbl1.ColB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the `WHERE` caluse

try this:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
      ColA INT
    , ColB CHAR(1)
    , ColC CHAR(1)
    );
INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( ColA, ColB, ColC )
VALUES  ( 1 , 'A', 'B' ), 
        ( 1 , 'C', 'D'),
        ( 1, 'E', 'D');
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT  T1.ColA,T1.ColB,T2.ColC
FROM    #temp AS T1
        INNER JOIN #temp AS T2
        ON T1.ColA = T2.ColA
WHERE   T2.ColC = 'D' AND T1.ColB = 'A'
```

RESULT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
        T1.ColA, T1.ColB, T2.ColC
    FROM 
        test  T1 , test  T2 
        where T1.colb='A' and T2.colc='D'
```